# Menu - Activity empty

Tags: java, android, menu

I try to do a tuto about Menu.

My JAVA code :

```
public class MenuActivity extends Activity {

    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        setContentView(R.layout.activity_menu);

    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu);
        MenuInflater inflater = getMenuInflater();
        inflater.inflate(R.menu.myfirstmenu, menu);
        return true;
    }

}
```

My XML "R.layout.activity_menu" code:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical" android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <!-- nothing because I just want display a menu -->
</LinearLayout>
```

My XML "R.menu.myfirstmenu" code:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" >
    <item android:id="@+id/item1" android:title="Item 1"></item>
    <item android:id="@+id/item2" android:titleCondensed="Item 2" android:title="Item 2 mais avec un nom assez long quand même">
        <menu>
            <item android:id="@+id/item3" android:title="Item 2.1" android:checkable="true"/>
            <item android:id="@+id/item4" android:title="Item 2.2"/>
        </menu>
    </item>
    <item android:id="@+id/item5" android:title="Item 3" android:checkable="true"/>
    <item android:id="@+id/item6" android:title="Item 4">
        <group android:id="@+id/group1" android:checkableBehavior="all">
            <item android:id="@+id/item7" android:title="Item 4.1"></item>
            <item android:id="@+id/item8" android:title="Item 4.2"></item>
        </group>
    </item>
    <group android:id="@+id/group2" android:enabled="false">
        <item android:id="@+id/item9" android:title="Item 5.1"></item>
        <item android:id="@+id/item10" android:title="Item 5.2"></item>
    </group>
</menu>
```

My problem is that when I run my app, nothing appear !
What I must do in order to display the three vertical dots and the app name ?

Thank for your answers  ;) 
Max

Comment: I've not hard button on my phone's side. I've an asus zenphone selfie.
version Android : 6.0.1
API : 23

Comment: did you somehow used NoActionBar theme ?? else there has to be default action bar showing. In case of NoActionBar, update your question so that we can provide specific answer.